# Why complete DAG is re-evaluating in every iteration of loop while using Cache/Persist in Pyspark?

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

When I tried with any single rule it takes 3 minutes for 2.5 million records, but when i run with complete 5 rules it take more than 3 hours. Every rule add extra time because DAG start evaluating from start.

```
def match_rows(dataframe):

'''
    In this function, I am trying to match all the rows of dataframe with each other
'''
  # some logic here
  return dataframe

df = spark.read.format("snowflake").options(**options).option("query", "SELECT * FROM TABLE").load()

#here some basic transformation

rules_list = ["rule1","rule2","rule3","rule4","rule5"]

for rule in rules_list:
  df.cache()
  # MATCH_STR is concatination of two three columns based on every rule
  df.withColumn("MATCH_STR", concate(*some_columns)) 
  df.repartition(col("MATCH_STR"))
  df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df.rdd.mapPartitions(match_rows), schema = df.schema)
  df.take(1) # also tried count
```

Comment: Every time caching?

Comment: yes after processing every rule.